# GMT offset in email headers

Tags: email, date

I really have a basic understanding of the world time zone clock. I looked at this site (http://www.pobox.com/helpspot/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=256) and this helps explain how to adjust the time according to its GMT offset on the date in email headers. But I just want clarification since I can't find it anywhere else.

Say you have information like this:

```
Thu, 27 Dec 2001 07:02:12 -0800 (PST)
```

Is it possible for a GMT value to be a value not divisible by 100 in email headers? In other words, is it possible for it to show (the 42 was arbitrary chosen):

```
Thu, 27 Dec 2001 07:02:12 -0842 (PST)
```

For those of you curious in what I'm doing, I'm trying to write a method that standardizes the time and date according to the time zone listed in email headers. You could argue that many programming languages support an automatic date and time conversion but I want to also know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible.  Currently, there are offsets that contain 30 and 45 in the last two digit positions.  The [Marquesas Islands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets#UTC.E2.88.9209:30.2C_V.E2.80.A0) is offset by -0930, and [Nepal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B05:45) by +0545.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I wanted to know.